# Wrong pin configuration of LM317 and LM337

Tags: bjt, pins, lm317, configuration

I have a problem with the circuit i was given
it seems that i made my circuit connection wrong. the pinconguration of LM317 and LM337 are on the left picture with 1-2-3 while i am suppose to connect it to the circuit but its required to have 2-1-3 connection, how can i connect the LM317/LM337 is there some sort of hold of transistor that can swith the 1-2-3, into 2-1-3

[image]

Comment: If it's any consolation you won't be the first person to bend the legs with pliers for a prototype board.  Just be careful and don't let them short or break off. (assuming a TO-220 package - SMD may be more difficult).

Comment: I love your artist's impression of a TO-220 package.

Comment: hold base of leads tight with needle nose pliers to prevent wirebond stress inside, in a vice.  Then bend leads with great care to fit easily when inserted.

Comment: Note that the pinouts of the LM317 and LM337 ARE DIFFERENT!  The LM317 is, left to right, Adjust, Out, In, while the LM337 is Adjust, In, Out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is such thing as adapter for changing pins.
You have these options:
a) carefully bend pins (swap position of pins 1 and 2)
or
b) scratch away traces for pins 1 and 2, use bodge wires to "cross" those traces
or
c) make new redesigned PCB with fixed positions of those pins

Comment: ... or just abandon all hope and try it anyway LOL (4th but unlikely option)

Comment: i just twisted the pins to fit the circuit and just used electrical tape to cover the part where the intersect, thanks for the suggestion